# Flutter: get default context? or load assets without context?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to load a json file in a class extending SearchDelegate to search through its content.

I have a method to load this file:

```
Future<void> loadCountryData() async {
    try {
      String data = await DefaultAssetBundle
          .of(context)
          .loadString("assets/data/countries.json");
      _countries = json.decode(data);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this requires a Buildcontext (context) that seems only to be available in the SearchDelegate build methods (like buildActions, buildLeadings, etc), but no outside like for example in the constructor.

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/SearchDelegate-class.html

As the @override xy build methods in SearchDelegate are called with every change in the search field, I would load my file over and over again, which is of course not ideal.
I want to load my file once at the beginning only.

Is there a way to get some sort of get default context that I could use for example in the constructor of SearchDelegate. Like in android (if I remmeber correctly)?

Or can I load an assets file without `.of(context)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [`DefaultAssetBundle`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/DefaultAssetBundle-class.html) is based on an [`InheritedWidget`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html) you will always **need** to *pass a context*.

`of` just looks up the widget tree based on a [`BuildContext`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/BuildContext-class.html) until it finds a `DefaultAssetBundle` widget. This means that you cannot retrieve a `DefaultAssetBundle` object without a `BuildContext`.

You *will need* to pass a `BuildContext` to your method. I could imagine a situation like the following:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return FutureBuilder(
    future: loadCountryData(context: context),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<JSON> jsonData) {
      if (!jsonData.hasData) {
        return Text('not loaded');
      }
      return Text('loaded'); // here you want to process your data
    },
  );
}

/// I am not sure what your decode returns, so I just called it JSON
/// I thought it would make more sense to return the JSON to use it in build
Future<JSON> loadCountryData({BuildContext context}) async {
  try {
    String data = await DefaultAssetBundle
      .of(context)
      .loadString("assets/data/countries.json");
    return json.decode(data);
  } catch(e) {
    print(e);
    return JSON.empty(); // imagine this exists
  }
}
```

As you can see I passed the `BuildContext` from the `build` method. The [`FutureBuilder`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) also allows to process the data in the build tree directly.

Comment: As a note, the flutter documentation suggests creating the future outside the build method. See https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html. Copy pasting from the docs: "The future must have been obtained earlier, e.g. during State.initState, State.didUpdateWidget, or State.didChangeDependencies. It must not be created during the State.build or StatelessWidget.build method call when constructing the FutureBuilder. If the future is created at the same time as the FutureBuilder, then every time the FutureBuilder's parent is rebuilt, the asynchronous task will be restarted."

Answer (score 9):

There is an option to get builtin `AssetBundle` without specifying a reference to `BuildContext`. Here is an example of how it could be done:

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart'; // is required

Future<void> loadCountryData() async {
    try {
        // we can access builtin asset bundle with rootBundle
        final data = await rootBundle.loadString("assets/data/countries.json");
        _countries = json.decode(data);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Description of function

````
  /// The bundle from the closest instance of this class that encloses
  /// the given context.
  ///
  /// If there is no [DefaultAssetBundle] ancestor widget in the tree
  /// at the given context, then this will return the [rootBundle].
  ///
  /// Typical usage is as follows:
  ///
  /// ```dart
  /// AssetBundle bundle = DefaultAssetBundle.of(context);
  /// ```
  static AssetBundle of(BuildContext context) {
    final DefaultAssetBundle result = context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<DefaultAssetBundle>();
    return result?.bundle ?? rootBundle;
  }
````

So you may simply use rootBundle instead of DefaultAssetBundle.of(context) for working with assets without context.

Answer (score 0):

You can give the `BuildContext` as a parameter through to `loadCountryData(BuildContext context)`.