# Error "The method [] was called on null" in Flutter while parsing Json

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I was creating a Flutter application which parses a simple JSON, and it works well but gives an error in Debug Console in VS Code,

My simple JSON file:

[image: json file]

With Lightest Code snippet :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(title: "J2", home: new Homepage());
  }
}

class Homepage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => new HomepageState();
}

class HomepageState extends State<Homepage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)  {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text("J2")),
        body: new Container(
            child: new FutureBuilder(
                future:  DefaultAssetBundle.of(context)
                    .loadString('assets/data.json'),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  Map<String, dynamic> mydata =
                      json.decode(snapshot.data.toString());
                  return new Container(child: new Text(mydata['city']));
                })));
  }
}
```

And it works well but with this error in the debug console, how can I overcome it? I am a beginner.

[image: Error Message]

Comment: Welcome to so. You need to copy your code. The screenshot is not proper.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter: get default context? or load assets without context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51109621/flutter-get-default-context-or-load-assets-without-context)

Comment: I think you can help me now.

Comment: The error message saying that your myData is null and myData['city'] is calling on a null object.

Comment: Thanks, the same is written is there but my question is why am I getting an error if I have data in mydata. Please check the JSON file also attached there.

Comment: @VishnuCS: thank you for wanting to improve questions here. Please do not use `code formatting` for proper nouns - things like Flutter and JSON are not themselves code, and should not be formatted as such.